# batch Seach and save values of text files on a single file

Tags: batch-file

I have a loot of text files like

```
{        
"name" : "john",   
"job"  : "janitor",   
"age"  : 70  
}
```

I what to search on all the files like `"name" : "%name%"`
and save the value on `%name%`

so it will save like

```
"john",
"max,
"ash"
```

with a batch file and save on a text what the commands I need to make this happens?

I don't know how to get the values from `"value" : "what I to save"`
edit:
not only a file but all files and on sub folder (as I said i need for a loot of files)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set name=
for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /s "name" *.name') do echo %%a>>newfile.txt
```

Comment: how I make it search all sub-folders and text files inside it on a list, like
"1",
"2",
"3"...??

Comment: add the `/s` switch to findstr to search subfolders and use *.txt to search all text files. Answer edited.